# What is the default value of justify content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

MDN has the default value of [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) as `normal` but that's not listed in the list of accepted values.

What is a `normal` value?

> **normal**
>   The items are packed in their default position as if no
>   justify-content value was set. This value behaves as stretch in grid
>   and flex containers.

I've seen other sites list it as [flex-start](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp). What is the default value?

I might have answered my own question by looking at the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-content):

> normal otherwise behaves as start.

Comment: What list was it? Maybe it was not added?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should pay attention because `justify-content` is defined in two different specifications and the trick is here.

The first specifciation is this one: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-content which is a draft one. The purpose of this specification is to allow us to align all kind of elements using the same properties:

> CSS Levels 1 and 2 allowed for the alignment of text via text-align and the alignment of blocks by balancing auto margins. However, except in table cells, vertical alignment was not possible. As CSS adds further capabilities, the ability to align boxes in various dimensions becomes more critical. **This module attempts to create a cohesive and common box alignment model to share among all of CSS.**

Inside you will find that `justify-content` can be used with all the elements and it has indeed a value called `normal`. The behavior of this value depend on the context where its applied.

For flexbox and CSS grid you will see

> `normal` behaves as `stretch`.

Also for flexbox you will see

> The `justify-content` property applies along the main axis, but since stretching in the main axis is controlled by flex, `stretch` behaves as `flex-start`.

---

All the above is still in Draft and has no support yet. To find the *real* values of `justify-content` you should either see the Flexbox or CSS grid specification.

In the [Flexbox one](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) such value doesn't exist:

> Name:  justify-content
>
> Value: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around
>
> Initial:   flex-start

Using `normal` value will either be considered as invalid and the initial value will be used or will be considered as valid and it will fall back to `flex-start`, the intial value.

In the [CSS grid specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-align) they are already linking to the draft one so you can assume all the values exist but you need to pay attention to the browser support of some of them.

---

Basically the MDN page is combining all the specifications which make it a but confusing.

In the future `justify-content` will have the following values:

```
normal | <content-distribution> | <overflow-position>? [ <content-position> | left | right ]

<content-distribution> = space-between | space-around | space-evenly | stretch

<overflow-position> = unsafe | safe

<content-position> = center | start | end | flex-start | flex-end
```