# align-items: end difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

MDN page used as an example (issue was first observed on my own page): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

`align-items: end` behaves in a strange way in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox aligns boxes to the bottom edge of the container row, Chrome - to the row top edge. To work around the issue I've switched to `flex-end`, it gives equivalent alignment on both browsers. But which behavior is (more) correct for the `end` value?

[Alignment difference screenshot from MDN demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAB44.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome is almost correct (little different). Because the `align-items` property doesn't have a value of `end`.

> #### 8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the align-items and align-self properties
>
> - Name:   align-items
> - Value:    **flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch**
> - Initial:  stretch
> - Applies to:   flex containers
> - Inherited:    no
> - Percentages:  n/a
> - Computed value:   specified keyword
> - Canonical order:  per grammar
> - Animation type:   discrete

However, it is not strictly correct. Because the value that can be applied by the `align-items` property will be replaced by that of Box Alignment Level 3, the `align-items` property defines a value of `end` in Box Alignment Level 3.

> #### 1.2. Module interactions
>
> The CSS Box Alignment Module **extends and supercedes** the definitions of the alignment properties (justify-content, align-items, align-self, align-content) introduced here.

According to Chrome Platform Status, the implementation status of CSS Box Alignment Level 3 is under development.

> #### Status in Chromium
>
> **Blink components**: Blink
>
> In development (tracking bug)

---

Reference:

- [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)
- [CSS Box Alignment - Chrome Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6173208034148352)

Comment: To sum it up, Firefox currently has _more_ complete implementation of CSS Box Alignment Level 3 (also seen at [blog page from 2017](https://blogs.igalia.com/jfernandez/2017/05/03/can-i-use-css-box-alignment/)) than Chrome currently has. The workaround I've posted enables the behavior I want on Chrome, since Chrome _does_ implement CSS Flexible Box Layout, older iteration of `align-items` property spec.

Comment: @AndrewBoyarshin in addition to this, MDN is confusing because it combine both Spec in the same page making it difficult to understand. Related question with similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57720598/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/54490884/8620333

Comment: Andrew Boyarshin, @TemaniAfif  Thanks for any additional information!